# Obtaining the expression for the Gibbs free energy in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

In chapter 8 of Peskin and Schroeder, on page 270, they define a function

$$\tag{8.6} G(M,H)=A(T)+B(T)M^2+C(T)M^4-MH$$

and $$\tag{8.7} M=\int d^3x\,s(x)$$

Peskin and Schroeder then claims that we can derive the following from the above two equations

$$\tag{8.8}G=\int d^3x \big[\frac{1}{2}(\nabla s(x))^2+b(T-T_c)s^2+cs^4-Hs]$$

where $\tag{8.4}B(T)=B(T-T_C), C(T)=c$

How did we get (8.8) from (8.6) and (8.7)? It's not true that $M^2=\int d^3 s(x)^2$.

Comment: I don't think he meant (8.8) follows from (8.6) and (8,7) in a literal sense. Page 270 was meant to introduce the mean field theory where M is assumed constant, and page 271 would give the natural extension to Landau-Ginzburg model by "analogy" with the mean field model. In short, consider everything from (8.7) onwards a separate theory